# Reducing Space between Title and Description in Search Results

Tags: php, css

I have created a search page for a website which displays the title and description. There's a lot of space between the title and description.

Here's the sample code for displaying the results

```
echo "<div class=\"main\"><ul><li><h3><a href='$link' style='text-decoration: none'><b>$title</b></a></h3>$description </div></li></ul>";
```

eventhough there is no "br" tag in between title and description there's a lot of space between them. How to get rid of this space. Could you let me know over here. Does line-height function works over here?

Here's the css code

```
.main {
position:relative;
font-size:1.01vw; 
color:Black;
font-family: Helvetica; 
top:3.5vw;
left:26vw;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the CSS for this.

Comment: .main {

     position:relative;
     font-size:1.01vw; 
     color:Black;
     font-family: Helvetica; 
     top:3.5vw;
     left:26vw;
     }

Comment: please setup as jsfiddle and call this question "reduce space around h3 element" !!

Comment: @LuisSiquot Am new here. Could you let me know how to Setup in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely to the HTML you are closing div before `</li></ul>` here at end `</div></li></ul>`

```
echo "<div class=\"main\"><ul><li><h3><a href='$link' style='text-decoration: none'><b>$title</b></a></h3>$description </div></li></ul>";
```

should be `</li></ul></div>`

```
echo "<div class=\"main\"><ul><li><h3><a href='$link' style='text-decoration: none'><b>$title</b></a></h3>$description</li></ul></div>";
```

and in CSS add

```
h3 {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b66my48d/)

Comment: Champ!! This is what I wanted. Thanks for your concern. I don't have enough Reputation to vote your answer.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance, don't worry about the upvote, it will be upvoted if it deserve a upvote but you can mark the answer correct, you are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `<h3>` is a block level element.

You need to add `style=float:left; width:auto` to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried it. If i assign float=left then the description is displaying after the title. I need the description in a new line after title but with no space.

Answer (score 0):

please use below CSS for reducing space:

```
h3{padding: 0;  margin:0; line-height:normal;}
```

Comment: just had a try with this and nothing happened. here is my css                       .main {

    position:relative;
    font-size:1.01vw; 
    color:Black;
    font-family: Helvetica; 
    top:3.5vw;
    left:26vw;
    }